# How to resolve merge conflict when the conflicting file are all package.json file?

Tags: merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I just git push my code to remote from local and build a new pull request to merge them to where I fork.
But I can not merge pull request because there have conflicts must be resolved.
All the conflicting files are the package.json file.

[image]

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to exclude the entire node_modules folder from source control; your app will work just fine if it is rebuilt from scratch (with `npm install`) as part of the build process.